# How to improve this TSQL Statement with CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, inventory-management

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around a query. It makes use of a subquery and an additional join, and I'm sure there is a way to construct it better, more readable and more performant, probably using CTE, but I'm not sure how.

Here goes: I have one table with a stock inventory history and another table with item price history. I need to calculate the value of the inventory for every historic entry using the latest price at that time.

For the purpose of this post I've simplified the tables a bit, using only one item from one stock. The inventory table looks like this:

[image]

```
select * 
from Temp.dbo.InvHist 
order by Date
```

And the historic prices looks like this:

[image]

```
select *
from Temp.dbo.PriceHist
order by Date
```

In order to get the latest price for every stock inventory date, I need first to get the right date from the price table:

[image]

```
select 
    InvHist.Date
    ,InvHist.Item
    ,InvHist.Amount
    ,max(PriceHist1.Date) DatePrice
from Temp.dbo.InvHist 
left join (
    select PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
    from Temp.dbo.PriceHist
    group by PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
) PriceHist1 on InvHist.Item = PriceHist1.Item and PriceHist1.Date <= InvHist.Date
group by 
    InvHist.Date
    ,InvHist.Item
    ,InvHist.Amount
order by
    InvHist.Date
```

And finally I join with the price table again in order to get the right price with which I can calculate the stock value:

[image]

```
select 
    a.*
    ,b.Price
    ,a.Amount * b.Price InvValue
from (
    select 
        InvHist.Date
        ,InvHist.Item
        ,InvHist.Amount
        ,max(PriceHist1.Date) DatePrice
    from Temp.dbo.InvHist 
    left join (
        select PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
        from Temp.dbo.PriceHist
        group by PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
    ) PriceHist1 on InvHist.Item = PriceHist1.Item and PriceHist1.Date <= InvHist.Date
    group by 
        InvHist.Date
        ,InvHist.Item
        ,InvHist.Amount
) a
left join Temp.dbo.PriceHist b on a.Item = b.Item and a.DatePrice = b.Date
```

So, does anybody have an idea on how to get to this result in a more efficient and elegant manner?

Comment: Your query looks fine as it is. A CTE is only really helpful if you have a common subquery that’s used more than once - or need to use a self-referential query (e.g. for recursion) which your query doesn’t use nor need. Performing joins on inner-queries is perfectly fine and indicates using SQL correctly.

Comment: If you’re getting poor performance, it means you’re missing an index or your `STATISTICS` objects are out-of-date. Have you looked at your query execution plans? They’ll tell you why a query is slow.

Comment: @Dai is correct.  However, I tend to prefer moving things out of the subquery and into a CTE because it makes it easier for me to test to make sure I'm actually selecting what I want though. It's also easier for me to think about when it's structured in a CTE but I don't personally know what the performance differences are.

Comment: Aside: First, avoid [premature optimization](http://xkcd.com/1691/)
(See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).). If there is a performance issue then look at the _actual execution plan_ to find the bottleneck(s).

Comment: CTEs are "syntactic sugar" for the most part, and will not affect performance. In the vast majority of cases, the query plan will be exactly the same after converting sub-selects to CTEs. If you're trying to optimize a query's performance, CTEs aren't your answer. If you're optimizing for readability, maintainability, and testability, then CTEs are great.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and solutions. It's great to get this kind of response. I'm currently reviewing the possible queries in the real context, checking the execution plans and setting some indexes. I'll report back afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

Since you did not provide the DDL+DML, I cannot test the queries. Moreover, any discussion regarding performance is totally senseless.

The following queries **were not tested** and just present the basic idea of using CTE instead of sub-query in your specific case. This answer is ONLY PRESENTED FOR THE SAKE OF LEARNING and not for any production reason.

### Converting the the main sub-query into one CTE:

As you can otice I simply copied the content of the sub-query into the CTE definition. This is pretty straightforward

```
;With MyCTE as(
    select 
        InvHist.Date
        ,InvHist.Item
        ,InvHist.Amount
        ,max(PriceHist1.Date) DatePrice
    from Temp.dbo.InvHist 
    left join (
        select PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
        from Temp.dbo.PriceHist
        group by PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
    ) PriceHist1 on InvHist.Item = PriceHist1.Item and PriceHist1.Date <= InvHist.Date
    group by 
        InvHist.Date
        ,InvHist.Item
        ,InvHist.Amount
)
select a.*,b.Price,a.Amount * b.Price InvValue
from MyCTE a
left join Temp.dbo.PriceHist b on a.Item = b.Item and a.DatePrice = b.Date
GO
```

### Now, let's take it to the next level and break the sub-queries inside the main sub-query into separate CTE

This step is a bit more complex (and I cannot be sure I did not made a syntax mistake since I could not test it).

```
;With MyCTE01 as(
    select 
        InvHist.Date
        ,InvHist.Item
        ,InvHist.Amount
        ,max(PriceHist1.Date) DatePrice
    from Temp.dbo.InvHist 
),
MyCTE02 as (
    select PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
    from Temp.dbo.PriceHist
    group by PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
),
MyCTE03 as (
    select Date,Item,Amount,DatePrice
    from MyCTE01
    left join MyCTE02 on MyCTE01.Item = MyCTE02.Item and MyCTE02.Date <= MyCTE01.Date
    group by MyCTE01.Date,MyCTE01.Item,MyCTE01.Amount
)
select a.*,b.Price,a.Amount * b.Price InvValue
from MyCTE03 a
left join MyCTE02 b on a.Item = b.Item and a.DatePrice = b.Date
```

Comment: Thanks for looking to this, it definitely great for learning. CTE's do make the query more readable, but don't add to performance in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I scaled it down using a cross apply to grab the correct price for that given date. It certainly trims down your execution plan, but it would certainly benefit from some indexing.

Take note of the table aliases, I used temp tables so I just aliased the same name so it would match up with your original query:

```
CREATE TABLE #InvHist ([date] date, Item varchar(20),Amount int)

INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('01-31-16','NDS.09011012',12)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('02-29-16','NDS.09011012',11)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('03-31-16','NDS.09011012',8)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('04-30-16','NDS.09011012',6)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('05-31-16','NDS.09011012',6)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('06-30-16','NDS.09011012',32)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('07-31-16','NDS.09011012',32)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('08-31-16','NDS.09011012',28)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('09-30-16','NDS.09011012',26)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('10-31-16','NDS.09011012',26)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('11-30-16','NDS.09011012',23)
INSERT INTO #InvHist VALUES('12-31-16','NDS.09011012',21)


CREATE TABLE #PriceHist([date] date, Item varchar(20), Price int)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('07-26-06','NDS.09011012',93894)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('10-25-06','NDS.09011012',98119)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('04-26-07','NDS.09011012',102828)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('06-23-07','NDS.09011012',102599)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('05-27-08','NDS.09011012',10701)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('05-26-09','NDS.09011012',89649)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('10-20-10','NDS.09011012',90783)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('01-26-12','NDS.09011012',89991)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('05-24-14','NDS.09011012',131496)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('03-28-15','NDS.09011012',141873)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('05-14-16','NDS.09011012',149738)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('06-25-16','NDS.09011012',15318)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('03-25-17','NDS.09011012',15459)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('10-21-17','NDS.09011012',156352)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('03-30-18','NDS.09011012',154869)
INSERT INTO #PriceHist VALUES('03-29-19','NDS.09011012',155154)


    SELECT 
        InvHist.Date
        ,InvHist.Item
        ,InvHist.Amount
        ,PH.PriceDate
        ,PH.Price
        ,InvHist.Amount * PH.Price InvValue
        FROM #InvHist InvHist
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) MAX(date) PriceDate, Price 
            FROM #PriceHist PriceHist 
            WHERE InvHist.Item = PriceHist.Item and PriceHist.date <=  InvHist.date
            GROUP BY Price ORDER by PriceDate desc) PH
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I actually prefer your solution for readability, interestingly however, applying this approach is slower. I'll explain in the answer

Answer (score 0):

So, the real tables are (in German) LagerbestandHistorie with 3,6 million rows and HerstellkostenHistorie with 61,9 million rows, both with dates ranging from 2006 to 2020. I added a clustered column store index to both of them.

I've compared just two queries, my initial with a subquery and one with cross apply.

The first looks like this:

```
select 
    a.*
    ,b.HerstellkostenkomponenteNr
    ,b.Betrag
from (
    select 
        lbh.Datum
        ,lbh.ArtikelNr
        ,lbh.LagerNr
        ,lbh.LagerplatzNr
        ,lbh.Menge
        ,max(hkh1.Datum) PreisDatum
    from LagerbestandHistorie lbh 
    left join (
        select hkh.Datum, hkh.ArtikelNr
        from HerstellkostenHistorie hkh
        group by hkh.Datum, hkh.ArtikelNr
    ) hkh1 on lbh.ArtikelNr = hkh1.ArtikelNr and hkh1.Datum <= lbh.Datum
    group by 
        lbh.Datum
        ,lbh.ArtikelNr
        ,lbh.LagerNr
        ,lbh.LagerplatzNr
        ,lbh.Menge
) a
left join HerstellkostenHistorie b on a.ArtikelNr = b.ArtikelNr and a.PreisDatum = b.Datum
order by
    a.Datum
    ,a.ArtikelNr
    ,a.LagerNr
    ,a.LagerplatzNr
    ,b.HerstellkostenkomponenteNr
```

It returned the result (12 million rows) in 26 minutes.

The other looks like this:

```
select 
    lbh.Datum
    ,lbh.ArtikelNr
    ,lbh.LagerNr
    ,lbh.LagerplatzNr
    ,lbh.Menge
    ,hk1.PreisDatum
    ,hkh2.HerstellkostenkomponenteNr
    ,hkh2.Betrag
from LagerbestandHistorie lbh
cross apply (
    select 
        max(Datum) PreisDatum
    from HerstellkostenHistorie hkh 
    where 
        lbh.ArtikelNr = hkh.ArtikelNr and hkh.Datum <= lbh.Datum
    ) hkh1
left join HerstellkostenHistorie hkh2 on lbh.ArtikelNr = hkh2.ArtikelNr and hkh1.PreisDatum = hkh2.Datum
order by
    lbh.Datum
    ,lbh.ArtikelNr
    ,lbh.LagerNr
    ,lbh.LagerplatzNr
    ,hk2.HerstellkostenkomponenteNr
```

It took 44 minutes to finish!

The execution plans look like this:

[image]

[image]

For now I'll stick with the first query. Thanks for all of your replies.

Comment: Your cross apply does not have a TOP(1) in it as was proposed.  and an order by of course.

Comment: True, I had to do that since the real table HerstellkostenHistorie has several price components per item.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace inner left join query with temp table `#temp`

```
left join (
        select PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
        from Temp.dbo.PriceHist
        group by PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
    ) PriceHist1 on InvHist.Item = PriceHist1.Item and PriceHist1.Date <= InvHist.Date
```

with

```
select PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
         INTO #temp
        from Temp.dbo.PriceHist
        group by PriceHist.Item, PriceHist.Date
```

and then use `#temp` in left join, You need to check logical reads with `Set  Statistics IO` or `profiler` of this query where the logical read heavy.

Comment: Why would a temp table improve the query?

Comment: For better sql plan try to avoid complex queries.